# Validating Listbox MVVM

Tags: c#, silverlight, validation, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn.Micro to do convention based binding of the contents of my listbox from a BindableCollection in my ViewModel.

I want to perform Validation on it so that when there is no selection and the user exits the form they get that nice red line around the listbox with the error message that they have to select a value. So far Caliburn has worked great for textbox validation but I can't seem to get it to work on the listbox!

On a side note, is there any way to forcibly run a complete validation from the VM? Currently I am merely doing manual validation by checking the values and changing them so it triggers the Validator which is a bit backwards..

Here is the code for my view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AddSessionDialogView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit">

<toolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" BusyContent="{Binding IsBusyStatusDisplay}">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,9" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TextBlock Text="Session Name" />
        <TextBox x:Name="SessionName" Grid.Column="1"  />
        <TextBlock Text="Scenario" Grid.Row="1" />
        <ListBox x:Name="Scenarios" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" DisplayMemberPath="Name" Margin="5" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="5">
            <Button x:Name="Cancel" Height="28" Margin="5" Content="Cancel" Padding="0,2" Width="75" />
            <Button x:Name="OK" Height="28" Margin="5" Content="OK" Padding="0,2" Width="100" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</toolkit:BusyIndicator>
```

Here is the (relevant) code for my viewmodel:

```
    public BindableCollection<Scenario> Scenarios { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select a scenario")]
    public Scenario SelectedScenario { get; set; }

    private string _sessionName;

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Session Name is invalid")]
    public string SessionName
    {
        get { return _sessionName; }
        set { _sessionName = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SessionName); }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IResult> OK()
    {
        if (SelectedScenario == null)
        {
            // This forces validation check, but doesnt show validation error on the view!
            SelectedScenario = new Scenario();
            SelectedScenario = null;
        }
        if (SessionName == null)
            SessionName = "";
        if (Validator.TryValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this), new List<ValidationResult>()))
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            IsBusyStatusDisplay = "Creating Session...";
            yield return new CreateSessionResult(SelectedScenario.Id, SessionName);
            IsBusy = false;
            yield return Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where's the link between the SelectedScenario property and your view?

Comment: It is being linked by Caliburn.Mirco

Comment: Where is your `INotifyDataErrorInfo` implementation? Where are you adding a validation error for the missing value? if `Vaidator.TryValidateObject` fails the list param you pass it will be populated with validation errors (as a side, that means you need to hold on to that list in a variable). Those errors should be added via your INotifyDataErrorInfo infrastructure....